# Restrict Google Geocoding to only true country results

Tags: php, google-maps, google-geocoder

At the moment, I can send `shsihsigsuygdjhgadjhg` through my Google Geocode API, and it returns an `APPROXIMATE` location type - even though I have just made it up!

I have restricted the request to just GB (United Kingdom), as per the documentation, but how can I restrict it to only return a `true` place?

**Parameters:**

```
$param = ['address' => 'shsihsigsuygdjhgadjhg','components' => 'country:GB'];
```

**Response:**

```
$response = \Geocoder::geocode('json', $param);
            $decoded_response = json_decode($response);
```

The response is:

```
+"results": array:1 [▼
    0 => {#314 ▼
      +"address_components": array:1 [▼
        0 => {#313 ▼
          +"long_name": "United Kingdom"
          +"short_name": "GB"
          +"types": array:2 [▼
            0 => "country"
            1 => "political"
          ]
        }
      ]
      +"formatted_address": "United Kingdom"
      +"geometry": {#320 ▼
        +"bounds": {#131 ▶}
        +"location": {#321 ▶}
        +"location_type": "APPROXIMATE"
        +"viewport": {#323 ▶}
      }
      +"partial_match": true
      +"place_id": "ChIJqZHHQhE7WgIReiWIMkOg-MQ"
      +"types": array:2 [▼
        0 => "country"
        1 => "political"
      ]
    }
  ]
  +"status": "OK"
}
```

How can I ensure it returns `ZERO_RESULTS` for approximate locations?

Comment: Just a suggestion: can we not use the partial match in the response and if it true can we not assume that it is not the exact match for what you are looking? Partial matches do deal with misspellings but if you want to deal with misspelling then my suggestion won't show any significance

Comment: I believe I could accept no `partial_matches`. I will implement this and wait for any more potential answers. Many thanks for your help @Coder.

Comment: I use google API's on a daily basis and their documentation doesn't make it easy. I will research further more and post if anything comes up useful @Ben

Comment: Thank you @Coder, I appreciate the help.

Comment: have you added the component to restrict the country to GB or just trying different solutions? @Ben

Comment: shsihsigsuygdjhgadjhg is is wales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the components field add the country value to the address field itself. The component field tries to get the component within the values you specified. It couldn't identify the address you are passing in but it recognizes the country and hence you are getting the partial match for it.

Instead of

```
$param = ['address' => 'shsihsigsuygdjhgadjhg','components' => 'country:GB'];
```

Try,

```
$param = ['address' => 'shsihsigsuygdjhgadjhg, GB'];
```

I am getting Zero results for the second implementation.

Comment: Works perfect. Such a small oversight! Many thanks @Coder.

Comment: Glad I could help! @Ben